# passing value into a different class

Tags: python

I have an array of data called msg.data[2] where i have used pubsub i now want to pass this data into the PlotCanvasExample Class

Here is where i call the class

```
self.pubsubText.SetLabel("This is the Contact Map for the chain "+msg.data[0]+" in the PDB file "+msg.data[1])
    frame = self.GetParent()
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.canvas = PlotCanvasExample(self,0, size=(100,100))
    sizer.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
```

Here is the class itself

```
class PlotCanvasExample(plot.PlotCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,size):
            plot.PlotCanvas.__init__(self,parent,id,style=wx.BORDER_NONE, size=(300,200))
            self.data = [(1,2),(23,2)]
            line = plot.PolyMarker(self.data)
            gc = plot.PlotGraphics([line],"CM view", "x-axis","y axis")
            self.Draw(gc, xAxis=(0,50), yAxis=(0,50))
```

How can i pass in the variable msg.data into this class

I am new to python so an explanation of how to do it would be nice so i can understand how to do it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may add setData method to PlotCanvasExample class and use this method maybe?

```
def setData(data):
    self.data = data
```

or if you need this parameter on object creation, you may add this parameter to init method of PlotCanvasExample.

```
class PlotCanvasExample(plot.PlotCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,size, data):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class P...:
    def __init__(self, parent, id, size, data):
        self.data = data 
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
self.pubsubText.SetLabel("This is the Contact Map for the chain "+msg.data[0]+" in the PDB file "+msg.data[1])
    frame = self.GetParent()
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.canvas = PlotCanvasExample(self,0, size=(100,100), msg.data)
    sizer.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.EXPAND,0)

class PlotCanvasExample(plot.PlotCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,size, msgdata):
            self.msgdata = msgdata
            plot.PlotCanvas.__init__(self,parent,id,style=wx.BORDER_NONE, size=(300,200))
            self.data = [(1,2),(23,2)]
            line = plot.PolyMarker(self.data)
            gc = plot.PlotGraphics([line],"CM view", "x-axis","y axis")
            self.Draw(gc, xAxis=(0,50), yAxis=(0,50))
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Arguments which need to be passed to a class should be placed in the `__init__` function.

Here is the Python documentation on [Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

the line of code `def __init__(self,parent,id,size):` is what you need to change to add the new parameter in.

When you create this class next time you can assign it in the `self.canvas - PlotCanvasExample()`

Example:

Class:

```
class PlotCanvasExample(plot.PlotCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,size,data):
```

Code:

```
self.canvas = PlotCanvasExample(self,0, size=(100,100), msg.data[2])
```

If your new to Python I would suggest taking a look through the docs. Also take a look at [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it will help when posting code on here.

:)